# rancher trident storage integration w/ rancherOS 1.55

Tags: nfs, rancher, trident, netapp, rancheros

i got two rancher cluster (deployed on vsphere). one with centos7 as base os and one with rancheros 1.55 (deployed via rancher ui w/ vsphere provider). on the centos7 based cluster trident integration 
installation w/;

```
kubectl create ns trident
./tridentctl install -n trident --kubelet-dir=/opt/rke/var/lib/kubelet --csi
./tridentctl -n trident create backend -f backend-ontap-nas-mc.json
kubectl create -f sample-input/storage-class-basic-ontap.yaml
```

on centos7 with installed nfs-utils it is working. but on rancheros 1.55 it is not. what I installed on all nodes on rancheros is:

```
sudo ros service enable kernel-extras
sudo ros service enable kernel-headers 
sudo ros service enable kernel-headers-system-docker 
sudo ros service enable volume-nfs
sudo ros service enable volume-cifs
```

and I can mount a pv which was created with trident on the working centos7 cluster on a racnheros node w:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o soft 10.31.102.168:/trident_pvc_09666bb0_e581_4945_800a_5cb850461332 /mnt/ /mnt/
```

but if I deploy applications in the rancheros cluster I still git the follwing errors:

```
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                                  Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                                  -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling        <unknown>              default-scheduler                     error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "redis-k5qrl-master-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Warning  FailedScheduling        <unknown>              default-scheduler                     error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "redis-k5qrl-master-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Normal   Scheduled               <unknown>              default-scheduler                     Successfully assigned redis-7g98w/redis-k5qrl-master-0 to trident-integration-worker1
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  10m                    attachdetach-controller               AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-9375c549-83d5-40d4-bd58-1c21e025c472"
  Warning  FailedMount             6m39s                  kubelet, trident-integration-worker1  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[redis-data config redis-tmp-conf default-token-5tgtv health]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount             4m49s (x3 over 8m51s)  kubelet, trident-integration-worker1  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-9375c549-83d5-40d4-bd58-1c21e025c472" : rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
  Warning  FailedMount             2m5s (x3 over 8m56s)   kubelet, trident-integration-worker1  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[health redis-data config redis-tmp-conf default-token-5tgtv]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount             99s                    kubelet, trident-integration-worker1  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-9375c549-83d5-40d4-bd58-1c21e025c472" : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetupAt failed: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```